# Realm with Swift 2.1 project won't build when importing RealmSwift (module file was created by an older version of the compiler)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm

I'm on the very latest Xcode 7.1 and my project uses Swift 2.1.   I followed all the directions on the [Swift website](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation-swift-20) for getting started (Dynamic Framework tab) and everything builds just fine until I try to `import RealmSwift` in my class.  The compiler throws the following error on the line I try to import RealmSwift:

```
error: module file was created by an older version of the compiler; rebuild 'RealmSwift' and try again: /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/iosDev/PROJECTNAME/RealmSwift.framework/Modules/RealmSwift.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule
```

All the files are in the `${PROJECT_DIR}` root (`RealmSwift.framework` and `Realm.framework`).

I have searched and searched for an answer, updated Xcode, deleted and reconfigured the library.  I'm not sure what it means by 'rebuild RealmSwift' (I'm new to swift).  The error only throws when I try to use the library in my class or use the Xcode plugin to create a new Realm Model Object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Realm Swift 0.96.2 was released on October 26 2015, adding support for Xcode 7.1 and Swift 2.1 This should address the issue you were seeing. Releases of Realm prior to 0.96.2 were built with Xcode 7 and supported Swift 2.0.

Comment: Thank you!!  I downloaded and set it up and it built perfectly the first time! I can't wait to dig into this library.  Thanks again!  This situation taught me a few things :)

Answer (score 2):

I am also using Realm in the latest version of Swift, but instead of the Dynamic Framework method, I use the Cocoapods version of the installation.

This works for me.

But anyway, this of course doesn't solve your problem :).

Most of the time this error can be solved by just cleaning your project. In the Xcode menu, Select `Product` and then `Clean`. I had this same error with some SQLite libraries I was using and this fixed it most of the time.

Comment: Yea I had a feeling using the Dynamic way would cause problems.  Let me try with cocoa pods and see if it works.  Cleaning didn't really work :(

Comment: Well... instead of cocoa pods I tried carthage.   Followed the instructions and got the exact same problem.  It must be files I'm getting from Realm. I will try with CocoaPods next but I assume it's the built files.

Comment: Same problems with Dynamic Framework. Problem was solved by switching to CocoaPods method.

Comment: Thanks, NeoHQ.  Which release of xcode are you using? 7.1?

Answer (score 1):

1. Clone the repo or download as a Zip file and open:  https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa
2. Open up a terminal window (mac) or some comparable alternative.
3. On mac, you'd change to the directory of the repo via. cd ~/Path/To/The/Repo command in the terminal window. cd stands for change directory.
4. Then, run this command: REALM_SWIFT_VERSION=2.1 sh build.sh build which will cause the project to be updated to Swift 2.1
5. Then, you'll be able to drag the frameworks back into your Project.

REALM_SWIFT_VERSION - Change with your build Version of Swift (hear latest Version of Swift is 2.1).

This Take Some Minutes to Build with Your Specific Version.